Density belongs to the Kullback-Leibler support of prior distribution, proof verification.
Suppose that we have some data generated from the a density $f_{0}$ with unknown true parameter $p_{0}$.  Then $f$ is the density with parameter $p$ that we use to infer the true density $f_{0}$ or equivalently the unknown parameter $p_{0}$. On the parameters of $f$ we place the prior distribution $\Pi$, since we use a Bayesian framework.
Now we have the following:
Proposition: Density $f_{0}$ belongs to the Kullback-Leibler support of prior distribution $\Pi$ if $\Pi(f:KL(f_{0},f)<\epsilon ) > 0 $ for all $\epsilon >0$

I create following example, to check if am able to prove it or in general if I make sense of the proposition.
We have some data generated from an $f_{0}$, $X\sim f_{0} = Bernoulli(p_{0})$, and we model the data with $f = Bernoulli(p)$. Then we calculate the $KL(f_{0},f)$.
$$KL(f_{0},f) = \sum_{x=0,1}f_{0}(x)\log \frac{f_{0}(x)}{f(x)} = (1-p_{0})\log \frac{1-p_{0}}{1-p} + p_{0}\log \frac{p_{0}}{p} \leq \log \frac{1-p_{0}}{1-p} + \log \frac{p_{0}}{p} = \log \frac{(1-p_{0})p_{0}}{(1-p)p} \ \ (*)$$
Now, we want to make $(*)$ less of $\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. To do that, I create the following set $A_{\epsilon} = (p:\frac{(1-p_{0})p_{0}}{(1-p)p}<e^{\epsilon})$.
So, for any $\epsilon >0$ that we choose we can restrict to $p$ in $A_{\epsilon}$ then it hold that $KL(f_{0},f) = \log(\frac{(1-p_{0})p_{0}}{(1-p)p}) < \log(e^{\epsilon}) = \epsilon$.
Now to prove that $\Pi(f:KL(f_{0},f)<\epsilon ) > 0 $ I have to prove that $\Pi(A_{\epsilon})>0$. For this purpose, I choose $\Pi$ being a Beta distribution for parameter $p$ with parameters $a,b>0$.
To prove that $\Pi(A_{\epsilon})>0$, I have to calculate the mass of those $p$ for which holds that $(1-p)p > (1-p_{0})p_{0}e^{-\epsilon}$.
I define as $y = (1-p)p$ and apply change of variable to the Beta distribution of $p$, and I find that the density of $y$ is
$$f(y) = f((1-p)p) = \frac{1}{B(a,b)}((1-p)p)^{a-1}(1-(1-p)p)^{b-1}|1-2p|$$
for $p\in[0,0.25]$.
Then, what I want to prove is that $\int_{e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0}}^{0.25}f((1-p)p)dp >0$
$$\int_{e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0}}^{0.25}\frac{1}{B(a,b)}((1-p)p)^{a-1}(1-(1-p)p)^{b-1}|1-2p|dp = \frac{1}{B(a,b)}\int_{e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0}}^{0.25}((1-p)p)^{a-1}(1-(1-p)p)^{b-1}(1-2p)dp \ \ (**)$$
The function $((1-p)p)^{a-1}(1-(1-p)p)^{b-1}(1-2p)$ is $\leq 0$ for $p \in [e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0},0.25]$
So, I take as $M = \text{infimum}_{p\in [e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0},0.25]} ((1-p)p)^{a-1}(1-(1-p)p)^{b-1}(1-2p)$ where $M> 0$.
Now I bound the integral $(**)$ from below by $M(0.25-e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0})$. The last think remaining is to prove that $M(0.25-e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0})$ is $> 0$. To do that I simply have to prove that $(0.25-e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0})$ is non negative or equivalently that $e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0}$ is smaller than $0.25$. The maximum that $(1-p_{0})p_{0}$ can attain is $0.25$ which is divided by $e^{\epsilon}$ positive and larger than $1$ for $\epsilon >0$, hence it is non negative. Thus, $M(0.25-e^{-\epsilon} (1-p_{0})p_{0})>0$.

The case where $p = 1$ or $0$ in the $KL$ take the overall $\log$ to be zero. I don't know if I succeeded or not or actually my proof makes any sense. I'm new in producing this kind of proofs, so any comment are appreciated.
